# How can I invoke a scriptblock in the caller's context?

Tags: function, powershell, scope, pipeline, scriptblock

Consider the following call site:

```
$modifiedLocal = 'original local value'
'input object' | SomeScriptblockInvoker {
    $modifiedLocal = 'modified local value'
    [pscustomobject] @{
        Local = $local
        DollarBar = $_
    }
}
$modifiedLocal
```

I would like to implement `SomeScriptblockInvoker` such that

1. it is defined in a module, and
2. the scriptblock is invoked in the caller's context.

The output of the function at the call site would be the following:

```
Local DollarBar   
----- ---------   
local input object
modified local value
```

PowerShell seems to be capable of doing this.  For example replacing `SomeScriptblockInvoker` with `ForEach-Object` yields exactly the desired output.

I have come close using the following definition:

```
New-Module m {
    function SomeScriptblockInvoker {
        param
        (
            [Parameter(Position = 1)]
            [scriptblock]
            $Scriptblock,

            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
            $InputObject
        )
        process
        {
            $InputObject | . $Scriptblock
        }
    }
} |
    Import-Module
```

The output of the call site using that definition is the following:

```
Local DollarBar
----- ---------
local          
modified local value
```

Note that `DollarBar` is empty when it should be `input object`.

[(gist of Pester tests to check for correct behavior)](https://gist.github.com/alx9r/a738a04c6feae503dcb637af41370653)

Comment: `$InputObject | % $Scriptblock`

Comment: Hmm...interesting.  That does seem to work.  Although I think it invokes in whatever context the scriptblock was defined, which is not always the caller's context.  But now I'm wondering whether that's what `SomeScriptblockInvoker` should actually do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can't.  The caller of a scriptblock does not have control over the [SessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714451(v=vs.85).aspx) associated with that scriptblock and that SessionState determines (in part) the context in which a scriptblock is executed (see the Scope section for details).  Depending on where the scriptblock is defined, its SessionState might match the caller's context, but it might not.

### Scope

With respect to the context in which the scriptblock is executed, there are two related considerations:

1. The SessionState associated with the scriptblock.
2. Whether or not the calling method adds a scope to the SessionState's scope stack.

[Here is a good explanation of how this works](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6139#issuecomment-364262570).

### The `$_` Automatic Variable

[`$_` contains the current object in the pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6).  The scriptblock provided to `%` is interpreted differently from the scriptblock provided `.` and `&`:

- `'input_object' | % {$_}` - The value of `$_` is `'input_object'` because the scriptblock is bound to `%`'s `-Process` parameter.  That scriptblock is executed once for each object in the pipeline.
- `'input_object' | . {process{$_}}` and `'input_object' | & {process{$_}}` - The value of `$_` is `'input_object'` because the `$_` in the scriptblock is inside a `process{}` block which executes once for each object in the pipeline.

Note that in the OP `$_` was empty when the scriptblock was invoked using `.`.  This is because the scriptblock contained no `process{}` block.  Each of the statements in the scriptblock were implicitly part of the scriptblock's `end{}` block.  By the time an `end{}` block is run, there is no longer any object in the pipeline and `$_` is null.

### `.` vs `&` vs `%`

`.`, `&`, and `%` each invoke the scriptblock using the SessionState of the scriptblock with some differences according to the following table:

```
+---+-----------------+-----------+-------------------+----------------------+
|   |      Name       |    Kind   |  interprets {} as |  adds scope to stack |
+---+-----------------+-----------+-------------------+----------------------+
| % |  ForEach-Object |  Command  |  Process block    |  No                  |
| . |  dot-source     |  Operator |  scriptblock      |  No                  |
| & |  call           |  Operator |  scriptblock      |  Yes                 |
+---+-----------------+-----------+-------------------+----------------------+
```

- The `%` command has other parameters corresponding to `Begin{}` and `End{}` blocks.
- For variable assignments made by the scriptblock to have side-effects on the SessionState associated with the scriptblock, use an invocation method that does not add a scope to the stack.  Otherwise, the variable assignment will only affect the newly-created scope and disappear once the scriptblock completes execution.

### The Most Viable Options

The two most viable options for passing [the tests in OP](https://gist.github.com/alx9r/a738a04c6feae503dcb637af41370653) are as follows.  Note that neither invokes the scriptblock strictly in the caller's context but rather in a context using the SessionState associated with the scriptblock.

#### Option 1

Change the call site so that the scriptblock includes `process{}`:

```
$modifiedLocal = 'original local value'
'input object' | SomeScriptblockInvoker {
    process {
        $modifiedLocal = 'modified local value'
        [pscustomobject] @{
            Local = $local
            DollarBar = $_
        }
    }
}
$modifiedLocal
```

And invoke the scriptblock using `SomeScriptblockInvoker` in OP.

#### Option 2

Invoke the scriptblock using `%` as [suggested by PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428736/how-can-i-invoke-a-scriptblock-in-the-callers-context#comment79815833_46428736).